# Frameworks/opt/telephony error when building with 4.4.3

Tags: git, building, cyanogenmod

I'm building a 4.4.3 ROM and encounter this error

```
frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/android/telephony/SmsManager.java:165: sendTextWithOptions(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,android.app.PendingIntent,android.app.PendingIntent,int) in com.android.internal.telephony.ISms cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,android.app.PendingIntent,android.app.PendingIntent,int,boolean,int)
iccISms.sendTextWithOptions(ActivityThread.currentPackageName(),
                       ^
frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/android/telephony/SmsManager.java:326: sendMultipartTextWithOptions(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>,java.util.List<android.app.PendingIntent>,java.util.List<android.app.PendingIntent>,int) in com.android.internal.telephony.ISms cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>,java.util.ArrayList<android.app.PendingIntent>,java.util.ArrayList<android.app.PendingIntent>,int,boolean,int)
iccISms.sendMultipartTextWithOptions(ActivityThread.currentPackageName(),
                           ^
frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IccSmsInterfaceManager.java:58: com.android.internal.telephony.IccSmsInterfaceManager is not abstract and does not override abstract method sendMultipartTextWithOptions(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>,java.util.List<android.app.PendingIntent>,java.util.List<android.app.PendingIntent>,int) in com.android.internal.telephony.ISms
public class IccSmsInterfaceManager extends ISms.Stub {
       ^
frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IccSmsInterfaceManager.java:490: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IccSmsInterfaceManager.java:596: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IccSmsInterfaceManagerProxy.java:38: com.android.internal.telephony.IccSmsInterfaceManagerProxy is not abstract and does not override abstract method sendMultipartTextWithOptions(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>,java.util.List<android.app.PendingIntent>,java.util.List<android.app.PendingIntent>,int) in com.android.internal.telephony.ISms
public class IccSmsInterfaceManagerProxy extends ISms.Stub {
       ^
frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IccSmsInterfaceManagerProxy.java:201: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IccSmsInterfaceManagerProxy.java:242: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
8 errors
make: *** [/home/thatkawaiiguy/Axxion/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/telephony-common_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs...
```

I have checked every repo managed by the ROM and not by CM and they've all been updated to 4.4.3. All telephony repos are from CM as well.

So can anyone help me with this error please? 
My source is up www.github.com/AxxionKat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using CM for telephony and framework_base, make sure you have both of these commits:

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_opt_telephony/tree/700c321998b6870df1437d3a334622b6212e523e

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/tree/a9fa542b1b1782152ab143a7818ee7f9f05c525b

They are both dependent on each other, so if you have the telephony commit but not the frameworks_base commit, it will fail with that error when you build.

Comment: Fixed it by looking through the repos and added the commit that caused the error, Thanks.